# Interpretation of AR, MA, ARIMA models

Tags: arima, acf-pacf

In literature have read, that model:
AR=> **acf** damped exponents and/or damped sine wave. **pacf** rare outputs beyond the confidence interval.
The number of outputs per confidence interval in **pacf** determines the order p of the AR(p) model.

MA=> **pacf** damped exponents and/or damped sine wave.**acf** rare outputs beyond the confidence interval.
The number of outputs per confidence interval in **acf** determines the order q of the MA(q) model.

1. Is it possible for the AR model, the values of the acf to cross the confidence interval or the values must be inside it?
   Is it possible for MA models, the values of the pacf to cross the confidence interval or the values must be inside it?
   [image]

2.The figure shows that the acf crosses the interval twice and the **pacf** once.What model could it be?

3.Is it possible to programmatically determine the damped exponents and the sine wave.What formulas to use to identify them?

4.This question most of all leads me to confusion. For example ARIMA (1,d,0). **acf** decays exponentially, **pacf** is only the first nonzero.
In my understanding it is AR (1)...

5.In General, I want to programmatically determine which model is currently AR, MA, ARMA or ARIMA.
On the Internet, a lot of interpretations of **acf**, **pacf**. And in many of them there is no clear logic to define models.
What can you advise?

Comment: I specifically divided the questions into numbers. Because someone doesn't know all the answers.